# Setting up a contact email using Google for Work

Tags: gmail

I currently am using Google for Work and have set up email accounts for the people in my company. Now I would like to set up a contact@example.com email address that forwards to multiple people.

The forwarding settings within Gmail itself only allow 1 address, so that won't work. I cannot find anything within the Google for Work admin page that lets me do this.

Surely this is possible somehow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a group.
2. Ensure that permissions on that group are such that anyone can send to it.
3. Add your desired members to that group.